# Tensor network simulation of quantum circuits with Python

Tags: qiskit, quantum-circuit, simulation, tensor-networks

What are the best tensor network-based simulators libraries in Python?

In particular, I'm interested in calculating the expectation value of an observable measured at the end of a quantum circuit.

EDIT: Qiskit has a [matrix product state simulation method](https://qiskit.org/documentation/tutorials/simulators/7_matrix_product_state_method.html), but I can't understand if I can compute the exact expectation values (without using the full state vector) or if I am limited to a finite number of shots.

Answer (score 1):

In Qiskit, if you want to compute the expectation value of a given operator $\hat{O}$ using the `matrix_product_state`-based simulation, you can use the primitive [`BackendEstimator`](https://qiskit.org/documentation/stubs/qiskit.primitives.BackendEstimator.html) as follows:

```
from qiskit.circuit.random import random_circuit
from qiskit.quantum_info import SparsePauliOp
from qiskit_aer import AerSimulator
from qiskit.primitives import BackendEstimator

num_qubits = 5
psi = random_circuit(num_qubits=num_qubits, depth=10, seed=42)
O = SparsePauliOp('Z' * num_qubits)

mps_simulator = AerSimulator(method='matrix_product_state')
estimator = BackendEstimator(backend=mps_simulator)
job = estimator.run(circuits=[psi], observables=[O])

print(job.result())
```

However, I don't think it is possible to compute $\langle \psi | \hat{O} | \psi \rangle$ exactly even if you pass `shots=None` to the method `BackendEstimator.run()`. The default number of shots is 1024 as you can see by printing the job result.

I also suggest to take a look at [`tenpy`](https://github.com/tenpy/tenpy), which is a pure Python library for the simulation of quantum systems with tensor networks.