# Exact expectation value of a quantum circuit simulated with the matrix product state method in qiskit

Tags: qiskit, quantum-circuit, simulation, tensor-networks

If I use the [matrix product state method in Qiskit](https://qiskit.org/documentation/tutorials/simulators/7_matrix_product_state_method.html) to simulate quantum circuits, I can obtain the exepctation value of an observable by using a finite amount of shots. Is there a way to obtain the exact expectation value wihout using the state vector?

If it is useful, I'm interested in $\langle \psi | Z_1 | \psi \rangle$, i.e. the expectation value of the Pauli Z matrix of the first qubit.

EDIT: I asked this question also in this [thread](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/30326/tensor-network-simulation-of-quantum-circuits-with-python), but it was an EDIT of the original question, so I thought it was better to create another thread.

Answer (score 0):

By default, the matrix product state method in Qiskit does not compute the state vector when computing the expectation value for a Pauli matrix. For a general matrix, it does compute the density matrix first.
For this purpose, should should define your observable as a pauli string, for example (if you are using qiskit runtime):

```
from qiskit.quantum_info import SparsePauliOp
observable = SparsePauliOp("XZ")
```

Comment: And then how do I calculate the expectation value for that observable?

Comment: You will get the expectation value in the result. See for example: https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/30326/tensor-network-simulation-of-quantum-circuits-with-python?rq=1